# VBA CODE getting changed for the user of China

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel application, written in VBA, which is working well with the users in North America region as well as for Europe region. But the same application is not working well for the users in China.

While debugging on user's system, I found out the **"±"** of the code is getting changed to **"?**.

**Can Someone help me on this?**

This application takes data from the hidden worksheet and copies in our UI in Excel. I tried changing language setting but it didn't work.

```
If ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer) Like "*" & "±" & "*" Then
    ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer).Select
    ActiveCell.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    MyText = ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer).Value
    Density = Left(MyText, Len(MyText) - 5)
Else
    Density = ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer)
End If

'Get data from the selected row
materialName = ext_mould_Search3.Range("D" & rowPointer)
Shore = ext_mould_Search3.Range("H" & rowPointer)
sap = ext_mould_Search3.Range("I" & rowPointer)
family = ext_mould_Search3.Range("J" & rowPointer)
short = ext_mould_Search3.Range("R" & rowPointer)
```

Comment: I also had a similar problem, the only solution that worked was installing a VM, in which installing an OS in mandarin (Chineese) and compiling my code there, but it was c++ not vba so I cannot guarantee it will work

Comment: @anand_v.singh Thank you for the response. Can you tell me bit more about your issue? 
Is it the case:The code complied in OS other than in mandarin was not working for the user in China?

Comment: I was working with python, using py2exe to convert it into executable, the character `|` looked like `?` and there were other similar issues, I then installed python in the target computer and made the exe in that, then the characters looked okay in Chinese PC but broke in my system.

Comment: I think there is a difference in how Unicode is implemented that come pre-installed in mandarin, however that is just a hunch

Comment: A similar thing then happened when I ported my code to c++., the characters would break based on where it was compiled. I didn't exactly figure out why it happened, but did find the workout that if I use a VM installed with Chinese/Mandarin windows, code compiled in it didn't break characters in Chinese systems

Comment: But even if compiled on VM, the characters would look different in my PC outside VM

Comment: I did not try to changing it from UTF-8 to Unicode, that might work though

Answer (score 1):

## Try using chrW for character codes of different languages

You can try the Unicode character for that string like the following:

`If ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer) Like "*" & chrw(&H00B1) & "*" Then`

That may fix your problem.  Worth a try.

Comment: You are welcome. If you found this helpful then, please upvote and accept as your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Chinese developer is not seeing correctly the `±` is because of the encoding they are using. In general,  for characters which are not in the the Ascii Character Codes Chart1 it is advisable to follow this rule:

- Create a very hidden worksheet in Excel, named `Settings` or something similar;
- Write the character there and refer it from there in your code;

[image]

In your case it would be like this:

```
If ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer) Like "*" & tblSettings.Range("A1") & "*" Then
```

If it is going to be used quite a lot, consider making an additional class with read-only constants, referring to that worksheet. E.g.:

```
Property Get GermanAE()
    GermanAE = tblSettings.Range("A1").Value2
End Property
```

This could be called in the following way:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
   Dim DedicatedStrings As New DedicatedStrings
   Debug.Print DedicatedStrings.GermanAE    'ä
End Sub
```

If you use just a few, you may consider using [named ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges) in Excel, and calling the chars (or the whole string) like this `[GermanAE]`, because it looks a quite understandable as well:

If ext_mould_Search3.Range("G" & rowPointer) Like "*" & [GermanAE] & "*" Then

This is a really good article for Encoding, explaining why the first 128 chars are quite the same for all settings:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was really helpful and things are working.